# HP-UX Boot from SAN

Tags: storage-area-network, hp, hp-ux

Does anybody knows how to make HP-UX boot from SAN?
Any help would be highly appreciated. I'm totally disappointed by HP's lack of documentation.

The server is RX8640 with HP-UX 11.31

Answer (score 4):

A quick google search for "HP UX 11.31 boot from san" [tells me](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Planning/Boot-from-SAN-11-31/td-p/4085688#.T-dybPXNmPM) that you have to go into the EFI menu at boot to configure the boot source -  if true, this is very similar to how you do these things on an Intel machine in either BIOS or UEFI.

Some additional hints - your question should include details of anything that you've tried to make this happen, and how it failed, so we know what you've already ruled out. You should also include more details about your hardware - like what the HBA(s) are and what your SAN looks like/consists of.

/edit - a further Google search, just on the title of your question, gives me [this document](http://bizsupport2.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01919982/c01919982.pdf). Looks like your server model is supported with all HBAs also supported. However, you still haven't described your SAN setup. If it's not FC, it looks like you can't boot from it.

Comment: EFI is a command based environment and it's too far more complicated than the first thought. Almost nothing could be achieved with lack of documentation.

Comment: If it's too complicated for you, *post your specific questions about what isn't working for you.*

Answer (score 0):

The command you're looking for is `setboot`

Check out `man setboot` or see [here](https://nixdoc.net/man-pages/HP-UX/setboot.1m.html)